# How to solve recurrence relation $a_{k}=7a_{k-1}-10a_{k-2}, \forall k\ge2$ with $a_{0} = a_{1} = 2$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Unfortunately I have no idea where to even start with this.  This is my first math class in almost a decade.  Can anybody tell me how i would go about solving for the following recurrence relation?  All help greatly appreciated.

$a_{k}=7a_{k-1}-10a_{k-2}, \forall k\ge2$ with $a_{0} = a_{1} = 2$

Comment: Do you know linear algebra and matrices?

Comment: I know of linear algebra.  I am more comfortable with Algebra than any other form of math.  Don't know much about matrices.

Comment: This may not be a good first math class to take if you are uncomfortable with mathematics, but if you are willing to study 2x of the other students then you can maybe do it.  A "college algebra" class may be preferred to take to brush up on your skills before what seems to be a combinatorics class.  I recommend having a discussion with your professor.  Be honest about what you do and don't remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the classical approach, start with the corresponding characteristic equation. If $$a_{k}=7a_{k-1}-10a_{k-2}$$ then $$r^2=7r-10$$ the roots of which being $2$ and $5$. So, the general form is $$a_k=c_1 2^k+c_2 5^k$$ Now, apply the conditions for $a_0$ and $a_1$; they will give you two linear equations with $c_1,c_2$ as unknwowns.

Comment: What is a root, and how did you get the roots to be 2 and 5?

Comment: Solutions of the equation which is a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: @OmarN Are you comfortable solving quadratic equations?

Comment: @DanielV I am not an expert, but I think I have a decent handle on quadratic equations for a novice.

Answer (score 0):

$a_k - na_{k-1} = m(a_{k-1} - na_{k-2}) \to m+n=7,mn = 10 \to n = 5, m = 2 \to a_k - 5a_{k-1} = 2(a_{k-1} - 5 a_{k-2})$. Put $b_k = a_k - 5a_{k-1} \to b_k = 2b_{k-1},k \geq 2, b_1 = 2 - 2\cdot 5 = 2 - 10 = -8$. Thus $b_k = b_1\cdot 2^{k-1} = -8\cdot 2^{k-1}$. Can you continue?

Comment: One thing that I think would help me is, what does $a_{0} = a_{1} = 2$ mean?

Comment: @Omar: We are given some partial info about a sequence of numbers. With this partial info as clues we have to solve the puzzle; The info are two kinds: how the $k$ th term of the sequence is related to the previous two terms; and the other info is what the first two terms are ($a_0$ and $a_1$).

Solving means getting a formula for the $k$th term $a_k$ directly in terms of $k$ and not in terms of other members of this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using matrices, you can combine:

$$a_{k+1} = 7~a_{k} - 10~a_{k-1}$$
with
$$a_{k} = a_{k}$$

To get:

$$\begin{align}
a_{k+1} &= 7~a_k - 10~a_{k-1} \\
a_{k} &= 1~a_k + 0~a_{k-1}
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} a_{k+1} \\ a_{k} \end{bmatrix}
%
&= \begin{bmatrix} 7 & -10 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_{k} \\ a_{k-1}\end{bmatrix}
%
\\ &= 
\begin{bmatrix} 7 & -10 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 7 & -10 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_{k-1} \\ a_{k-2}\end{bmatrix}
%
\\ &= 
\begin{bmatrix} 7 & -10 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 7 & -10 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 7 & -10 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_{k-2} \\ a_{k-3}\end{bmatrix}
%
\\ \vdots
%
\\ &= 
\begin{bmatrix} 7 & -10 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^k
\begin{bmatrix} a_{1} \\ a_{0}\end{bmatrix}
%
\end{align}$$

The eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix} 7 & -10 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ are $5$ and $2$, so for some matrix $P$:

$$\begin{bmatrix} a_{k+1} \\ a_{k} \end{bmatrix}
%
= P~\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}^k~P^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} a_{1} \\ a_{0}\end{bmatrix}$$

So for some numbers $X$ and $Y$:

$$a_{k+1} = X~5^k + Y~2^k$$

You can use the initial conditions $a_0 = a_1 = 2$ to find $X$ and $Y$:

$$2 = X~5^1 + Y~2^1$$
$$2 = X~5^0 + Y~2^0$$

To get:

> $x = \frac{-2}{3}$ and $y = \frac{8}{3}$

to get the total solution:

> $$a_{k+1} = -\frac{2}{3}~5^k + \frac{8}{3}~2^k$$

If you aren't comfortable with matrices, and just want "how do I do this" rather than "why does this work", then I recommend Claude's answer.

Comment: I think I understand now.  The only part I am confused on is when you got to 2=X 5^1+Y 2^1 and 2=X 5^0+Y 2^0, how did you come up with the answer of -2/3 and 8/3?

Comment: $$X + Y = 2 \implies X = 2 - Y \implies 2 = (2 - Y)~5 + 2Y \implies Y = \frac 83 \implies X + \frac 83 = 2 \implies X = -2/3$$.  Frankly, this is a fairly high school level task, to solve 2 equations and 2 variables.  I really strongly suggest talking to your professor about whether you should be taking a college algebra class instead.  You won't enjoy mathematics if you are taking courses that you aren't prepared for.

Comment: PS, that's college algebra, not abstract algebra.  Make sure not to confuse those.